# What is the relationship between a simple regression's $F$ value for $R^{2}$ and $t$ value for a slope?

Tags: regression, interpretation, r-squared

I have a question that states:

In a simple regression, if the $F$ value for $R^{2}$ is 4, then the $t$ value for the slope $b$ must be...?

I'm having trouble understanding how to figure out the solution. Would someone be able to help?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What relationship do you know between t-distributions and F-distributions?

Comment: Hi Dave! I understand that If you square a t(df) you get an F(1, df), and that the t-percentiles can be obtained by a simple transformation from the “diagonal” entries of an F-table. I think it may just be the wording that's throwing me off, but would the F value just need to be square-rooted to get the t value?

Comment: Why don’t you try a quick simulation in R (or your preferred software) to check if you’re right?